# i have error on sql syntax to create a pivot from a subquery, for MySQL version

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I create a store procedure using table tempShcedule like that, but, my store procedure can't execute done, store procedure have an error,, but I haven't been able to find the wrong script, please help me to find and fix the script store procedure

i have table like this :

| NIK | name | dt | tIn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aaaa | 01/11/2022 | 08.00 |
| A | aaaa | 02/11/2022 | 08.00 |
| A | aaaa | 03/11/2022 | OFF |
| A | aaaa | 04/11/2022 | 14.00 |
| A | aaaa | 05/11/2022 | 14.00 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| Z | zzzz | 30/11/2022 | 08.00 |

and the result I expected was like this :

| NIK | name | 01/11/2022 | 02/11/2022 | 03/11/2022 | 04/11/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 06/11/2022 | .... 30/11/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aaaa | 08.00 | 08.00 | OFF | 14.00 | 14.00 | 23.00 | OFF |
| B | bbbb | 14.00 | 23.00 | 23.00 | OFF | 08.00 | 08.00 | 14.00 |
| .... | .... | ... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |
| Z | aaaa | 14.00 | 08.00 | 14.00 | 23.00 | OFF | 23.00 | 23.00 |

this is my store procedure query to solve this, but this is have error like the screenshot error:

```
BEGIN

set @sql=NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when day(dt) = ''',
      day(s.dt), 
      ''' then tIn end) ',
      day(s.dt)
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM
  tempShcedule s;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT concat(NIK,'' - '',name)nm ', @sql,' FROM tempShcedule GROUP BY nm');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

the store procedure have new error like this :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max(case when
> s.dt = '2022-11-01' then s.tIn end) `2022-11-01`,max(case when s.d' at line 1

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, i'll update the question

Comment: No, you removed the error message entirely. It should still be in the post, as text, where it is readable and searchable. The issue was the image, not the error message itself. Please [edit] to put that message in as text, in a blockquote.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you, I have updated the question for the better

Comment: You try to use date literals as columns names. But you do not quote them properly. So they are treated as arithmetic expressions (2022-11-01=2010) - with obvious error.

Comment: @Akina : `'max(case when s.dt = date(',s.dt, ') then s.tIn end) ',s.dt` -> i changed it like this the result is still an error too

Comment: Add `SELECT @sql;` before PREPARE and look at the composed SQL code.

Comment: Use ```CONCAT('max(case when s.dt = ''', s.dt, ''' then s.tIn end) `', s.dt, '`')```

Comment: @Akina there is a new error when in `set sql`, the error reads like this 
>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tempShcedule s GROUP BY NIK' at line 1

Comment: Provide complete value obtained in `@sql`.

Comment: how to provide @akina?

Comment: Add it into your question as an update.

Comment: Okey, i have updated my question on new error @Akina

Comment: The error message is NOT enough. Complete SQL text which cause this error needed.

Comment: @Akina I have been able to solve the error, but I returned to the previous error, try to check the code and error above, I have updated the question above again

Comment: I have asked you to provide both SQL code and error message. But I do not see SQL code (the output for `SELECT @sql;`) yet..

Comment: @Akina : i can't execute `SELECT @SQL` becuase this error :  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max(case when s.dt = '2022-11-01' then s.tIn end) 2022-11-01,max(case when s.d' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

The sheer amount of quotes and string concatenation makes it kind of hard to navigate around. You can reduce the amount of adding single quote using [`quote` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) in mysql.

The following query is working, though I am not sure in regard to the bigger picture. I saw your initial question has a lot of stuff going. However keep in mind that the query below still don't know what to do with non-existing datum. It only says `null` if stuffs missing.

```
set @sql = null;

select group_concat(
        distinct(
          concat('max(case when dt = ',
           quote(dt),
           ' then tin end) as ',
           quote(dt)
          )
        )
       )
 into @sql
from tempShcedule;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select nik, name, ', @sql,' FROM tempShcedule group by nik, name');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

See fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nPT1syCSCura6g55zymKco/0

It would be best if you can test stuff step-by-step, like printing the `@sql` by doing `select @sql;` and see the output. See if the query actually makes sense. On your latest comment, the issue arise due to unquoted date in the middle of query.

```
end) 2022-11-01,m
     ^-- need to enclose this date within quotes
```

Spreadsheet won't go extinct any time soon and I believe this kind of use case might be better done on it.